# APS Forge and IoT integration issue

Tags: visualization, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am working in BIM real-time dashboard test by using aps iot example - [https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo/blob/master/services/iot.mocked.js#L1-L46](https://stackoverflow.com)

The platform work, and without any error message.

I can duplicate the sensor and modifiy the location.
But I get lost in sensor objectid part, I try to change it (for example, I change the sensor-1 objectid to 33333, but it lost with room interlink. heatmap malfunction.)

I had already retrieve and view derivative tree(JSON), I try to dig out what's going on, but I had no idea on that.

And I tried to use alternative way to resolve the problem, means I try to change the element color directly, I tried use the setThemingColor method to change the element directly.
[https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setthemingcolor-dbid-color-model-recursive](https://stackoverflow.com).

I rewrite in server.js to force change element color, but it's not working, and run error message - referenceerror: three is not defined forge.

So I need to resolve two different part of issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `objectId` is an optional property that you can use to specify the actual element of your design to apply the heatmaps to. The ID itself can be obtained from the viewer, for example, using the `viewer.getSelection()` method that returns a list of IDs of all currently selected design elements.